# How to get a circle to snap its size to a specific radius?

Tags: inkscape, snapping

I have a diagonal line and I want it to be the radius of a circle. I can snap the centre of the circle to the first cusp node fine and extend it out from there, but for some reason it won't snap the path of the circle to the other cusp node. What am I doing wrong here and how can I circumvent it?

[image: Not snapping]

Comment: disclaimer: not an Inkscape user, so suggesting my Illustrator workflow. Can't you measure the length of the line, and then have Inkscape draw a circle with that exact size as the radius?

Comment: @Vincent This workflow isn't needed in Inkscape. The software has comprehensive snapping options to enable exactly what the OP wants.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Inkscape 1.0, you can use a path effect for it, no snapping required:

Option 1:

- draw the diameter instead of the radius, then
- Path > Path effects > + > Ellipse from points : dropdown 'force circle'.

Option 2:

- select the radius
- Path > Path effects > + > Show experimental > Circle (by center and radius)

Answer (score 6):

In the Snapping Controls bar, make sure you select the following options.

- Enable Snapping
- Snap Nodes Paths and Handles
- Snap to Paths
- Snap other Points
- Snap rotation centres

With the Bézier Tool selected, When you approach the circle's path, it will snap to it displaying "Handle to Path".

Example (snapping options shown right)

[image]

If you need to do this in reverse, and already have a line, then you could use the Measure Path extension to measure it, then draw a circle from one of the end nodes, holding down <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd> as you click and drag, then edit the Rx and Ry values in the Tool Controls Bar to match the line length.

Example

[image]

Comment: Nice answer, but the question wasn't how to snap a line given a circle: it was how to snap a circle given a line. Usually the snap affects the mouse cursor, and while we are drawing a circle this works only when the given line is horizontal or vertical. For other angles, I cannot see an immediate way to snap the circle (e.g. you can rotate the line until is vertical, draw the circle, re-rotate the line). A tricky question.

Comment: @PaoloGibellini If the OP needs to do it in reverse, then there's a Measure Path extension, which can measure a line at any angle, then it would be possible to draw a circle holding down Ctrl+Alt while you drag from one of the end nodes, and then edit the Ry and Rx values in the Tools Control Bar to be the same as the line length.

Comment: @PaoloGibellini I've added that to my answer.

Comment: This doesn't help me--the measure path tool gives a rounded off precision number to what has been specified. I'm looking for it to be as precise as possible (hence why I'm interested in a snap).

Comment: @Nicholas If you are looking for that level of precision, then Inkscape or similar vector graphics software is probably not the software for you. Maybe have a look at using some actual CAD software instead.

Comment: @Nicholas well you do understand that the value gets rounded on save. SVG just works that way.

Answer (score 3):

Just in case the radius is already drawn but you must insert a circle like in your example try this:

[image]

Have all snaps to point and guides ON, but keep snap to grid and bounding box OFF.

1. Drag from the top a horizontal guide to the center of the wanted circle. It snaps.
2. Duplicate (=select, press Ctrl+D) the radius. Drag duplicate's (=green) rotation center to the center of the wanted circle. It snaps. Rotate the duplicate to horizontal. It snaps, too.
3. Draw a vertical line (blue) starting from the end oft the rotated duplicate
4. Draw a circle from the wanted center point (=hold Shift and Ctrl) until it snaps to the vertical line.

Comment: I was already answering, but your answer is more simple. You can also use a guideline instead of the vertical blue line.

Comment: How do you rotate the duplicate to be exactly horizontal? The program only wants to rotate it a specific number of degrees *relative to the object itself*, without regard for what angle the line is starting in.

Comment: @Nicholas  You have revealed an error. I had switched from the move tool to the node tool and of course it snapped. The wrong radius cannot be seen in the small screenshot. I have fixed the answer. Fortunately snap to guides works when rotating.